# IBM Worklight - how to rename an application and change its icon, splash image

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

We've used an existing example application to start a proof of concept with Worklight, we've made a lot of changes to the original code and we would like to change the application name and customize its icons and splash image. We've managed to make the aforementioned changes (Name, icons and splash) inside xCode, however this doesn't serve the future purpose of an automated build from Worklight to ipa.

Could you please let us know what steps are involved to:

1. How to rename an existing application in Worklight (changing only the application-descriptor.xml doesn't change the generated binaries though).
2. How to change icons and splash screens for app.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new application for a Worklight project, the application name is used throughout several files, so you will need to find all occurrences of the given application name and change them. These are:

- main HTML filename
- main CSS filename
- main JavaScript filename
- inside main HTML filename (references to the main CSS and JavaScript files, title)
- Inside application-descriptor.xml (the elements: `displayName`, `description`, `mainFile`)

Note, the filenames should not matter to you. In the future they will, hopefully, always get a generic name (like index.html or main.css. ...).

The app icon title in the device is controlled by the `displayName` element in application-descriptor.xml.

As for the icons and splash images, you can simply place thme (regular icon, retina icon, splash image, retina splash image) with the appropriate filenames in the "nativeResources" folder (sits next to the "native" folder) and they will be copied during build time to the native project (which you will eventually open in Xcode).

You can find out the correct filenames inside the native >> Resources folder.

---

*quote:*

> however this doesn't serve the future purpose of an automated build
>   from Worklight to ipa.

Worklight will, of course, never create an .ipa file for you... that's the role of Xcode.

Comment: Idan we are still working on the renaming process, not as straightforward as we thought... we've managed to change everything but now when we click on a process the task opens up in a full-blown safari browser and not inside the actual worklight application... any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. You're supposed to change all of the above in Eclipse and then re-build and deploy the .wlapp.

Comment: @nechavarria, is your question answered?

Comment: Idan we will retake this task during this week and will get back to you. Thanks a lot!!