# IBM Worklight - how to change the app name in the URL path of accessing adapters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I got an requirement to change the URL of accessing adapter: make the URL lowercase.

The current URL: localhost:9080/worklight/apps/services/api/ABC/iphone/query

The "ABC" in the URL is my app name.

How to make it lowercase?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely upper-case because when you created the Worklight application in Eclipse, you gave it the name `ABC`.

If you're not far long into your app development, I would suggest to simply create a new application, this time with the lower-case name `abc`.

Otherwise there is this answered question: [IBM Worklight - how to rename an application and change its icon, splash image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969028/ibm-worklight-how-to-rename-an-application-and-change-its-icon-splash-image)

The process of renaming is not simple, so I do suggest to just create a new app and copy/paste the logic of the current app to the new app.